# Display UIWebView from html string with font and css

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I want to display an view from html code
here is my code to add to main view from web view,

```
- (void) createWebViewWithHTML{
//create the string
NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"<html><head><title></title></head><body style=\"background:transparent;\">"];

//continue building the string
[html appendString:@"body content here"];
[html appendString:@"</body></html>"];

//instantiate the web view
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

//make the background transparent
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

//pass the string to the webview
[webView loadHTMLString:[html description] baseURL:nil];

//add it to the subview
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

}
but problems are:
1, the background of uiwebview is white color not transparent
2, i want to add css and custom font to my code, please give me an example or solution or sample code
Thanks for your helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:
http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-uiwebview-with-a-transparent-background-in-iphone/

Hope it helps!